# Copy file and place it to different directories based on the month created of the file

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I want to copy the patch files of the current month into the assigned quarter directories as the destination. If the month is:

| `MONTHS` | `QUARTER DIRECTORIES` |
| --- | --- |
| `January to March` | `{{patch_oracle_qdir}}/Q1` |
| `April to June` | `{{patch_oracle_qdir}}/Q2` |
| `July to Sept` | `{{patch_oracle_qdir}}/Q3` |
| `October to December` | `{{patch_oracle_qdir}}/Q4` |

So far I have this script using ternary to identify the quarter directory

```
    - name: DETERMINE QUARTER DIRECTORY
      set_fact: 
        patch_oracle_qdir: "{{ansible_date_time.month == 08  or ansible_date_time.month == 09 or ansible_date_time.month == 10 | ternary(patch_oracle_base/Q3, patch_oracle_base/Q4) }}"
      #with_together:
      #   - "{{Q1}}"
      #   - "{{Q2}}"
      #   - "{{Q3}}"
      #   - "{{Q4}}"

    - name: COPY THE PATCH FILE INTO TARGET SERVER ORACLE
      synchronize:
        src: {{files_base_dir}}"
        dest: "{{patch_oracle_qdir}}"
        owner: yes
        group: yes
        mode: push
      register: extract_patch_oracle
```

Not tested this yet, but is it okay to use ternary or just use with_together loop?

Comment: "So far I have this script " ... and then you stopped typing. What is your question, or the error that code is producing? Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page,
and pay especial attention to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section

Comment: Not tested this yet, but is it okay to use ternary or just use with_together loop?

Comment: I mean, if it works for you and your colleagues can follow what's going on, then "it's okay". SO isn't designed to answer opinion questions, only _problems_ that you're having with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the variable below

```yaml
patch_oracle_qdir_index: "{{ '%m'|strftime()|int // 3 + 1 }}"
```

gives the index

```yaml
patch_oracle_qdir_index: '4'
```

---

**Notes**

1. Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    patch_oracle_qdir: /tmp
    patch_oracle_qdir_index: "{{ '%m'|strftime()|int // 3 + 1 }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: patch_oracle_qdir_index
    - debug:
        msg: |
          dest: {{ patch_oracle_qdir }}/Q{{ patch_oracle_qdir_index }}
```

gives (abridged)

```bash
shell> date +%B
November
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  patch_oracle_qdir_index: '4'

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    dest: /tmp/Q4
```

---

Q: ***"What does this line mean?"***

```yaml
{{ '%m'|strftime()|int // 3 + 1 }}
```

A: See the self-explaining tasks below

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ '%Y-%m-%d'|strftime() }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ '%m'|strftime() }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ '%m'|strftime()|int }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ '%m'|strftime()|int // 3 }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ '%m'|strftime()|int // 3 + 1 }}"
```

give

```yaml
  msg: '2022-11-11'
  msg: '11'
  msg: '11'
  msg: '3'
  msg: '4'
```

Comment: Thank you for this. May I ask what this line means? "{{ '%m'|strftime()|int // 3 + 1 }}"

Comment: I added an example. Feel free to test it on your own.